# Blazor .Net5.0 WebAssembly Server?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

Ive been watching the .Net Conference and I am confused on the following screen shot.  I am familiar with Blazor and the 2 hosting flavors, WebAssembly and Server.  However, this screen shot seems to be a hybrid.

[image]

The BlazorNet5.Server looks to be a Server version of Blazor, however, the Component type is being labeled as a BlazorNet5.Client.App as well as a script reference to Blazor.WebAssembly.js which normally is blazor.server.js.   Can someone explain what is going on here and what the benefits are?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the new server side prerendering feature of Blazor WASM. Available in .Net 5

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about it?  Its a server side blazor app that is mocking a wasm?

Comment: It's an ASP.Net server prerendering the WASM app : https://jonhilton.net/blazor-wasm-prerendering/